# Word or phrase to describe the "overly feminine" stereotype

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

While writing up a persona, I am trying to describe a woman who (I say) is confidently female, but not "overly feminine".

By this I wish to mean the stereotype of a sophisticated woman who appreciates luxury products, wears pearls and likes well tailored black dresses and bags. And I wish to exclude the stereotype of women who wear all-pink, frilly dresses, girly stuff etc.

**Is there a word or phrase that can replace "overly feminine" here?**

(Apologies for the politically awkward subject, this is a persona I am writing for a design brief and I do not intend disrespect.)

Comment: "Overly feminine" is a marked statement - the best way to say someone is not overly feminine is to say the unmarked statement: nothing at all. But that's different from a woman who dislikes pink and frills. You aren't being specific enough.

Comment: I am looking for that word or phrase to describe the woman/girl who likes pink and frills, so we can specifically exclude that stereotype. 

The practical purpose is to communicate to designers that even though this is a brief for a womens' design, don't go down the frilly pink path.

Comment: I might call her a *girly-girl*, but that is very informal.

Comment: You need the feminine equivalent of *macho*.

Comment: By "overly feminine" you mean a very young woman who always dresses in pink, wears too much perfume, makeup, and seems to emulate a Barbie doll? That type person could be described as being "adolescent."

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Splork! (You'all know that one? Coined by Laura Blanchard on soc.history.medieval to denote the sound of coffee hitting the keyboard through the nose.) I was going to say that just "girly" would do in the original sentence, I see there's a proposal for "girly-girl", but you went one better.

Comment: @DavidPugh if you want to pilfer the idea, go ahead! :) The "ultra feminine" type is more prevalent in Northern Europe me thinks.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I don't think so. When Latins watch Norwegian women, they ask whether they have to do military service – and given the climate, the striding in boots makes better sense than undulating in heels. Brazilians they're not. Watching Nogettes teeter in stilettos after the office party (being drunk as skunks doesn't help) can be painful.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think Barbie doll is an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "looking for a word or phrase to describe the woman/girl who likes pink and frills"

> **Girlish** *Adj*. 1. girlish - befitting or characteristic of a young girl; "girlish charm"; "***a dress too schoolgirlish for office wear***"; see The Free dictionary [girlish](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/girlish)

Comment: I am looking for the opposite word really, a word to describe the un-elegant, if you will.

Comment: But "a woman who ... appreciates luxury products, wears pearls and likes well tailored black dresses and bags" is the epitome of elegance and class.

Comment: I agree 'elegant' describes the woman. However I am looking for a word or phrase to describe the woman/girl who likes pink and frills, so we can specifically exclude that stereotype. The practical purpose is to communicate to designers that even though this is a brief for a womens' design, don't go down the frilly pink path. So what I want to say is, a woman who is elegant, but NOT "overly feminine" - but using a more appropriate phrase than "overly feminine"...  "too girly", perhaps?

Comment: like, "prissy"?

Comment: also, possibly, "girlish"

Comment: Girlish might work. The ideal phrase would also be the opposite of elegant, while still being a socially positive and acceptable style/stereotype for women with minimal negative connotations (except maybe for the style police :P).

Comment: The "style police" = fashion*istas*

Comment: This one was troubling and "girlish" was the best I could do. Hope it will suffice. Thanks for your vote of confidence, Pranab. I upvoted you yesterday but you deserve more than one.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

A **reserved woman**

En example from [elitedaily.com](http://elitedaily.com/women/why-limiting-your-online-appearance-will-naturally-make-people-more-interested-in-you/640897/), 'Why Being **Reserved** Makes You Sexy, Not Boring'

> The **reserved woman** always intrigues us; wondering what she does all
>   day and how she snagged that man or job keeps us interested in her
>   life because we know nothing about it.

Reserved in [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reserved)

reserved (rɪˈzɜːvd)
adj

- cool or formal in manner; restrained, silent, or reticent
- avoiding familiarity or intimacy with others; formal or self-restrained.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you're trying to *exclude* the fluffy, pink, girly stereotype - you might try "not frilly".  That should kind of suggest the flounces-and-frills type of design that is favored by that girlish style.  Maybe even "not pink and frilly", depending on how much you want to be specific about excluding.

If you're looking for a word to describe your character, who is looking for luxury, well tailored, and such - perhaps elegant, smooth, or sleek would describe that style.  You might mention something like reserved or understated (as opposed to gaudy or glitzy), to maybe further nudge them towards a black dress and pearls look, instead of something brighter in style.

So, [your character] is looking for something luxurious, sleek and understated, rather than frilly and pink.  I think that might get the message across without wandering too far into dangerous territory.

Answer (score -1):

Classic or modest describes a woman who wear pearls and black dresses.

Ameezing describes a spoiled and self-centered girl as in "Or my ga, those pumps are ameezing (then slurps from a venti mocha frappa-chino).  [Credit to Kroll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDtj07mbyMw&list=PL_p6VyM7EJ4DZXuRTGKio28LIPxvn3iCd).